# Send a list of objects through ajax to an action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a base class for model:

```
public abstract class ViewModel {
   public string Title{ get; set; }
   public abstract string Type { get; }
}
```

and I created two classes:

```
public class SomeViewModel: ViewModel  {
    public override string Type { get { return "a type" } }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}


public class AnotherModel: ViewModel {
    public override string Type { get { return "another type" } }
    public string System { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have a view which uses these classes ( I send a `List<ViewModel>` to the view)

```
@model List<ViewModel>

...

<form>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model)
</form>
```

I have a view called `ViewModel.cshtml` in `DisplayTemplates` folder

```
@model ViewModel

@if(Model is AnotherModel) {
    // do something and print value
    AnotherModel conv = Model as AnotherModel;

    @Html.TextboxFor(model => conv.System)
} else {
   // put some inputs here
}

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Type)
```

---

Now I have a javascript ajax. I want to send a list of objects to an action which renders a partial view

The ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'My/GetData',
   dataType: "html",
   type: "POST",
   data: { id: 3, myList: $("form").serialize() }
   success: function(data) {
      // print html
   }
});
```

and action looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetData(int id, List<ViewModel> myList){
   ...
   return PartialView("myView", someModel)
}
```

---

**The problem** is `myList` parameter which always is 0 as length (count)... I expect to be 2...

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: shouldn't there be a `foreach` somewhere in one of the views?

Comment: 1 mistake i see is that you don't have a [HttpPost] attribute on you GetData method. You are using Ajax method 'POST'

Comment: @DawoodAwan: Mistake corrected

Comment: @danludwig: No, is not needed because `DisplayFor` do his job with iteration.

Comment: What does the JSON representation of `$("form").serialize()` look like? Have you tried changing the action parameter to `ViewModel[] myList`

Comment: @danludwig: If I use `[]` then it will be null... The serialization may looks like: `ViewModel[0].Type=tt&ViewModel[0].System=-1&ViewModel[1].Type=oo&ViewModel[1].Id=1` but I'm not sure because I provided here simple models (with less parameters than I have in my project)

Comment: @SnakeEyes that is the URL querystring representation. What do you get when you do this? `JSON.stringify($("form").serialize())`

Comment: What I Provided above but between `"` and `"`

Comment: There should be a for loop. And DisplayFor will never help, use EditorFor `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++){@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i]);}`

Comment: @SnakeEyes: you really need to confirm the serialization. Looking at the code you have, I'm thinking your field names are ending up as `model[0].System`, etc. The data you should be passing should have name params in the query string style post data like "[0].System". Fix that and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `myList` would contain no elements is no doubt because the control names do not match the property names, but you have more problems than just that. The `Type` property in the derived models has a getter only, so even if the collection did bind correctly (it wont as discussed below), the value of `Type` would be an empty string because there is no setter on the property (the `IsReadonly` property of `ModelMetadata` is set to `true` so the `DefaultModelBinder` ignores it), and you would have no way of knowing what type your objects were.

Next, The `DefaultModelBinder` will only initialize instances of `ViewModel`, not your derived types, so only those properties of `ViewModel` with public getters/setters would be bound (for example the `Id` property of `SomeViewModel` wont exist)

I am assuming your models must be far more complex than what you have shown (otherwise there would be no point doing this) which means your template (and it should be an `EditorTemplate` not a `DisplayTemplate`!) must be polluted with lots of other logic to determine which properties to render and how (and a nightmare to debug).

The simple solution would be to create a view model with collections for each type (probably also including the `id` property you want to post, but not sure what that is or how it relates to your model) and then use an `EditorTemplate` for each type

```
public class TypeVM
{
  public List<SomeViewModel> SomeTypes { get; set; }
  public List<AnotherModel> AnotherTypes { get; set; }
}
```

/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AnotherModel.cshtml

```
@model SomeViewModel
....
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id)
```

/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SomeViewModel.cshtml

```
@model SomeViewModel
....
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.System)
```

and in the view

```
@model TypeVM
....
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeTypes)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.AnotherTypes)
```

If you need to submit using ajax, then

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetData", "My")'; // don't hard code your url's!
var data = $("form").serialize();
$.post(url, data, function(data) {
  // update DOM
});
```

and post back to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetData(TypeVM model)
```

This would mean rendering different the types in groups. If that is not suitable, then you need to create a custom `ModelBinder` where you can use the `bindingContext` to read the `Type` property and initialize each derived type and set the appropriate properties. A daunting task, but [The Features and Foibles of ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx)
 might help you get started with how to approach it (the section on Abstract Model Binder).

Side note: Do you really need to post back the whole form in order to return a partial view?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I found out after two hours of investigation. The abstract class cannot be instantiated (because is abstract)... So I changed my mind and I followed exactly your pattern.